# How do I load data from the database once per day?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Our ASP.NET MVC 3 website display contents from an external ticketing system and querying this database slows down page load (we display it in the every page footer).

We didn't find any deferred loading approach for this .NET API (Zendesk) and were considering to load this content once per day.

How can we implement this in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Thanks.

EDIT: Maybe, there is a way to set some content to be loaded as the last one?

Comment: Oh, there are so much ways to do that... what have you tried? What problems did you encounter? you should update question to include more details and more narrow kind of problem

Comment: Why in ASP.NET MVC 3 ? It'll be simplier to use an external and scheduled task to do this.

Comment: You could add those results to the ASP Cache and set an expiry time to 24 hours. Or load them from the client side using ajax once the page with the other contents has already been loaded

Comment: @archil: The .NET API provides simply a function call that returns a collection of items. This call can be quick, slow or never return in the case the server is down. This means that even our website is down because of this. We never tried any approach yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the API data, only retrieving it every 24 hours or if the cache is flushed.

It all depends on your detailed requirements really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use   ASP.NET cache (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx). Is's very flexible instrument for caching your data. You can set sliding expiration or dependencies for caching items.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of SQL server (or other RDBMS) available you could use an SSIS job to get the data once per day, then your web app can display data from your local database.

Comment: The .NET API provides simply a function call that returns a collection of items.

Comment: Then can you use a wcf client to get the data, before saving it locally?  what have you tried?